# Town Report (Number of orders)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, report

I am creating a report orders by town.

```
SELECT S.city, count(*) as NumOfOrders
    FROM Shop as S
    LEFT JOIN orders O ON O.ShopID = S.ShopID
WHERE O.status = 4
Group by S.city
```

The result display something like this:

```
Town 1  |   53
Town 2  |   45
Town 3  |   64
```

It work fine but I want to display all towns even no orders?

Expected Result:

```
Town 1  |   53
Town 2  |   45
Town 3  |   64
Town 4  |   0
Town 5  |   0
```

I have tried replacing LEFT JOIN to RIGHT JOIN, that dont even work. Same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you are using a LEFT JOIN, you are using the o.statu column in a Where Clause and hence the rows with null values (cos of left join) will be dropped.

Try this:

```
SELECT S.city, 
        SUM 
        (
        CASE 
            WHEN ISNULL(O.status) THEN 0
            ELSE 1
        END  
        ) as NumOfOrders     
    FROM Shop as S  LEFT JOIN orders O 
      ON O.ShopID = S.ShopID 
 WHERE IFNULL(O.status, 4) = 4 
    GROUP BY S.city
```

Comment: I don't see any issue with the SQL as such. Are you getting any error?

Comment: It displayed all the towns but the number of orders is random which should be 0

Comment: It seem counting the numbers of city  in the Shop table

Comment: I am not sure what's wrong.. Can you post the results that you got?

Comment: It seem counting the number of S.city from the Shop table. (Note: There are mulitle rows of same city name in the Shop table)

Comment: @Cybernate, You want a zero instead of 1 in `IFNULL(O.status, 1)`!

Comment: @Cybernate, you can probably simplify that `ISNULL` even further to just `COUNT(O.status)`, which counts the number of records with status not null.

Answer (score 6):

Your filter is excluding the ones with no orders. Try getting the condition into the join and you should be fine.

```
SELECT S.city, count(O.any_non_nullable_field) as NumOfOrders
    FROM Shop as S
    LEFT JOIN orders O ON (O.ShopID = S.ShopID AND O.status = 4)
Group by S.city
```

Comment: It seem counting the number of S.city from the Shop table. (Note: There are mulitle rows of same city name in the Shop table)

Comment: Shouldn't you be getting the count from the Orders table O?

Comment: Good. I always try to encourage people to correct their mistakes, rather than, say, downvoting them.

Comment: Very noble of you. I think I met some wrong people when I started in SO. I've been downvoted for much less. Sometimes, with no reason at all. On my behalf, what I can say is that when I downvote, I show my face and my reason. I will try to follow your example from now on.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the cleanest way possible, but wrapping the above query into a subquery and left joining to the Shop table would work.

```
SELECT s.city, IfNull(x.NumOfOrders, 0)
FROM Shop as s
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT S.city, count(*) as NumOfOrders
    FROM Shop as S
    LEFT JOIN orders O ON O.ShopID = S.ShopID
    WHERE O.status = 4
    Group by S.city
) x
ON s.city = x.city
```

Answer (score -1):

You are doing an outer join correctly but you have the condition in your WHERE clause that O.status must be 4.